# How can I use a different version of openssl with perl?

Tags: perl, openssl

I am writing Perl script on linux box that uses `SOAP:Lite` and `LWP::Protocol::https`. Those modulea use openssl to negotiate SSL connections.

I needed to a resent version openssl to get TLS 1.2, but sysadmin doesn't want to upgrade current one and give me a local version of openssl.

How can `perl` point to that local version. Will I have to rebuild all Perl modules?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to rebuild the [Net::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay) module which provides the OpenSSL binding for [IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL) which itself is the library used by [LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) (and thus [SOAP::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite)) for SSL since LWP version 6.

To rebuild Net::SSLeay with a specific version of `OpenSSL` you need to have a C-compiler and the specific SSL library and their header files installed in a directory which you can specify with `OPENSSL_PREFIX`. See the [Net::SSLeay README](https://metacpan.org/source/MIKEM/Net-SSLeay-1.78/README) for detailed build instructions.

Comment: For Mac OS X with homebrew'd openssl, see https://gist.github.com/andyjack/7dd4d7b65d262b2a6e56, viz: 
`CONFIG_ARGS=$( cat <<_EOF_ | tr '\n' ' '
INC=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
LDDLFLAGS="-bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
LD="env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.11 cc"
LDFLAGS="-fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
_EOF_
)
cpanm Net::SSLeay --configure-args "$CONFIG_ARGS" --interactive --verbose
`

Comment: I downloaded openssl form https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay where can a source for openSSL 1.0+ be found?

Comment: @MUYBelgium: There is a file called README in the distribution. The name of the file might be a clue of what do do with it. To cite from the file: *"To download OpenSSL, see https://www.openssl.org/"*